# Swift : Play a Facebook Video using an AVPlayer

Tags: ios, facebook, video, uiwebview, avplayer

I need to play videos from several video sources (Facebook & Instagram) for my iOS app.

I create an AVPlayerItem with the video URL and it's work for Instagram but not for facebook.

URLs layout are as following :

Instagram :

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/xxx.mp4
```

Facebook :

```
https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=xxx
```

Is there a way to play Facebook videos in AVPlayer or should I use UIWebview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the way how I recovered the video.

The following URL allow recovering an iFrame, not a playable file `https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=xxx`

According to [Facebook Video API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/video), you can get "A URL to the raw, playable video file" with "source" field.

I made a test call with Postman. You can see the correct URL highlighted which can be used successfully in AVPlayer.[image]

Comment: but how would my users get that url from a facebook video share link?

Comment: @DavidSeek You can't get this URL directly from Facebook. You need to  use the Facebook API

Comment: There is also an other solution, using a web view with the embed player

Comment: i do have the facebook api. but how do i get a playable link? using webview is no option. i want the player in a cell

Comment: You can see on the answer the underlined URL (on the screenshot), set the AVPlayer with this URL, it works 

Comment: And maybe it's not a good option for you but you can add a webview in a cell with dynamic size

Comment: i know that this url works. but the question for me is. how is that practical. you know. the user just gets the facebook share link. he doesnt have postman and the possibility to filter the source himself. that is why i'm asking how to get to the raw link

Comment: In a Facebook share link, there is the id of the Facebook post, so, make an HTTP request like I did with postman, but in your app. You can easily do it with Alamofire. Then parse the JSON to get the raw link. Did I reply to your answer? If you need more explanation, just tell me

Comment: if i try to share a link from Jimmy Kimmel or whatever, I only get a link to their sites profile with a bunch of videos. but I will try it with alamofire and see what the request puts out. thank you very much

Comment: Yes, but for exemple, I took a share link from a Facebook post with a video : https://www.facebook.com/JimmyKimmelLive/videos/10154738649333374/. "10154738649333374" is the Id. With that Id, you can make the http request (https://graph.facebook.com/10154738649333374). In response to the request, you have a JSON that you can parse to get the raw link.

Comment: When you take a share link from Jimmy Kimmel page, can you see the Id?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/JimmyKimmelLive/videos/10154738649333374/

so yes

Comment: The link from source property under JSON isn't playable even in browser or anywhere else , doesn't work

Comment: @vishal I don't know what's your problem but it's work for me.
Here is the playable link extracted from graph.facebook.com/10154738649333374 (try to click on the link) :
https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t43.1792-2/15377035_577056069156244_5225572604647047168_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjE1MDAsInJsYSI6MTUxOSwidmVuY29kZV90YWciOiJzdmVfaGQifQ%20u00253D%20u00253D&rl=1500&vabr=729&oh=7670e799b2e64014e929fd89c52c380a&oe=5889ADB7#15592466163226293886

Comment: Can you tell me which files to look for ?

Comment: 1. Open in a new tab the JSON response from : https://graph.facebook.com/10154738649333374

Comment: 2. Search "source" in the document

Comment: 3. Copy the link and paste it in a new tab. It should open a the video

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/1823111461291957 can you try this ? The link in source field is bit different than one you posted , i mean base URL

Comment: how to get the source property from this type of links https://www.facebook.com/shreyaghoshal/posts/10155774118036484  . please provide the code for objective-c. I am using the facebook version greater than 2.4

Comment: Looks like solution outdated, I can't find raw link in in Facebook API